# Using a dedicated proxy container in front of Rails app container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm in the process of `dockerizing` a Rails app before deploying it to production.

I was able to create a 2 container (db+app) system and now I'm trying to add a proxy container (with Nginx) to run in front of the app to serve static assets.

I have created a basic container starting from `nginx:1.11-alpine` with the config below

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:3000;
  }
}
```

I'm now able to point my browser to `http://0.0.0.0` and get the root page, however, static assets are (obviously) not served and I don't know how to proceed.

Should I copy the static assets from the app container to the proxy container?

How should I update the Nginx config file?

My docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

services:
...
  app:
    build: .
    command: bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - postgres:db
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.11-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    links:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to share `assets` directory from app container to nginx container through shared volume mount and configure nginx to serve those files.